# getting a pattern using like,wildcards in sql

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, wildcard, sql-like

I have two columns visit and visit_sequence,

```
Example table

Visit         Visit_sequence
1             43:65:34:21:343
2             22:78:113:37
3             43:465:72:21:1187:542

The semi colon is present in the field.
```

Now if I want to check if a visit has visit sequence which contains the numbers 43, 65 and 21. What condition (shortest condition) should I use?

If I write

```
 case when visit_sequence like '%:43:%:65:%:21:%'
```

or

```
 case when visit_sequence like '%43%:%65%:%21%'
```

These definitely wont work. I don't need the whole code, just the part after `like`.

Comment: Why are you looking for 43,65,**21** in one place and 43,65,**343** in two others?

Comment: This is why storing composite, formatted data in a single column leads to problems. If there was a table storing `Visit, Step and Sequence` with separate rows for each step in the sequence, the query would be trivial. Also, what RDBMS?

Comment: @joe G Joseph Im working on teradata ..

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from visits
 where ':'+visit_sequence+':' like '%:43:%'
   and ':'+visit_sequence+':' like '%:65:%'
   and ':'+visit_sequence+':' like '%:21:%'
```

I hope you have a small table, because your denormalized storage format is not going to perform well with any type of query thrown to it for this problem.

Comment: i need it in one line. case when ... like '  ' .. arent there other wild characters apart from % that will solve this issue?

Comment: If teradata supported REPLACE natively (not udf), I could suggest something else, but it doesn't even have that.

Comment: yeah i guess this can work, but i dont have a small table .. table is huge .. working on teradata

Comment: Then you're looking to write a UDF and passing your column and search criteria into it. Well, maybe, it's still row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) if you are using ORACLE

```
  select *
  from visits
  where REGEXP_LIKE (visit_sequence, '43:.*65:.*21')
```